# Lotus Notes C++ API - No platform specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

When compiling my DLL project in Visual Studio (after only including the lncppapi.h), an error is thrown: No platform specified.

I've played around with some options in Build > Configuration Manager. Tried pointing to Win32 and x64 with no luck but I have little to no clue what I'm doing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by appending `W32` to the Preprocessor Definitions in the Project Properties of Visual Studio under Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions.